# What bug is this? Manchester, UK

Tags: entomology

The creature appears to have a green body with 5 legs of the same size, and one longer than the rest. It moved this long leg around, and it looked like it was using it to sense it’s surroundings.

Location: Manchester, United Kingdom

[image]

Comment: Looks like a harvestman (daddy long legs). What size was it? You can try identifying it with the tool here: https://harvestmen.fscbiodiversity.uk/ The image isn't clear enough for me to try.

Answer (score 3):

That looks like what I would call a "daddy long legs", also known as *harvestmen*. These are arachnids of the order [*Opilones*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opiliones). There are some [30 species of harvestmen](https://harvestmen.fscbiodiversity.uk/) found in the UK. The webpage https://harvestmen.fscbiodiversity.uk/ has a very useful identification tool and based on it, I believe your photograph shows a [*Leiobunum sp. A*](https://harvestmen.fscbiodiversity.uk/?&tbv=&selectedTool=vis4&taxon=Leiobunum%20sp.%20A&imgi=6):

[image: leiobunum on a human hand]

Please visit the site itself for more details as it doesn't allow copying.

Comment: Great ID resource! Bookmarked it for later use.

Comment: It's my understanding that crane flies are called "daddy long-legs" in the UK.  So using that name for a harvestman over there might cause confusion.

Comment: @EldritchWarlord yep, but I was raised calling them daddy long legs, and I'm not about to change that because I now live in London :) but that's why I mentioned the BrE version too. They're called harvest men there.